# Changing Valuebox font

Tags: r, markdown

I am using flex dashboard in my markdown document. First row of my page are value boxes. Is there a way I can resize and change the fonts of value boxes without implementing Shiny. I tried with ## row {data-width=10} but it does not seems to be working.

Comment: Can you provide your code to reproduce the problem?